# How do I change the text of Facebook Messages in Facebook Chat using a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

Follow-up question for bonus points: an answer to the question here:
[Chrome Extension: Modify messagetext in facebook-chat when submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529083/chrome-extension-modify-messagetext-in-facebook-chat-when-submitted)

What I tried:

manifest.json

```
    {
        "manifest_version": 2,

        "name": "FB Test Change Example",
        "description": "This extension changes text in Facebook Messages",    
        "version": "1.0",

        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*",    "https://www.facebook.com/*"],
                "js": ["messageswap.js"]
            }
        ],

        "permissions": [
            "activeTab",
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
        ]
    }
```

messageswap.js

```
    document.body.onload = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('original', 'replaced');
    }
```

This breaks my Facebook. It works once on page load, but fails each subsequent time I try to reload the page. I've searched online and through the extension pages and found nothing. Facebook uses a more complicated model I assume -- would I have to do this using React? Is there a better way to do this in plain JavaScript? Where should I start?

Comment: No, you don't have to use React, just a basic understanding of DOM (assigning html rebuilds everything inside the container thus losing the event handlers and attached properties) so although the referenced answer is for Greasemonkey script but the solution applies here. There should be lots of other better duplicates, use search on "replace text in html dynamically", try different terms.

Comment: indeed a dup of many other similar questions. i also picked the same as dup even thou there are other more clear dups (excercise left to the o.p.)